# How to best calculate average issue age for a range of historic dates (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

**Objective:**
I need to show the trend in ageing of issues.  e.g. for each date in 2021 show the average age of the issues that were open as at that date.

**Starting data (Historic issue list):**. "df"

| ref | Created | resolved |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 20/4/2021 | 15/5/2021 |
| a2 | 21/4/2021 | 15/6/2021 |
| a3 | 23/4/2021 | 15/7/2021 |

**Endpoint:** "df2"

| Date | Avg_age |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 | x |
| 2/1/2021 | y |
| 3/1/2021 | z |

where x,y,z are the calculated averages of age for all issues open on the Date.

**Tried so far:**
I got this to work in what feels like a very poor way.

1. create a date range (pd.date_range(start,finish,freq="D")
2. I loop through the dates in this range and for each date I filter the "df" dataframe (boolean filtering) to show only issues live on the date in question. Then calc age (date - created) and average for those. Each result appended to a list.
3. once done I just convert the list into a series for my final result, which I can then graph or whatever.

```
    hist_dates = pd.date_range(start="2021-01-01",end="2021-12-31"),freq="D")
    result_list = []
    for each_date in hist_dates:
        f1=df.Created < each_date      #filter1
        f2=df.Resolved >= each_date    #filter2
        df['Refdate'] = each_date      #make column to allow refdate-created  
        df['Age']= (df.Refdate - df.Created)
        results_list.append(df[f1 & f2]).Age.mean())
```

**Problems:**
This works, but it feels sloppy and it doesn't seem fast.  The current data-set is small, but I suspect this wouldn't scale well. I'm trying not to solve everything with loops as I understand it is a common mistake for beginners like me.

Comment: You should include the code for your solution which you think is deficient - it along with your written explanation will help the reader understand what you are trying to do. A sample dataset to work with will help potential answerers test your solution and craft one of their own. [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you two solutions: the first one is step-by-step for you to understand the idea and process, the second one replicates the functionality in a much more condensed way, skipping some intermediate steps

---

First, create a new column that holds your issue age, i.e. `df['age'] = df.resolved - df.Created` (I'm assuming your columns are of `datetime` type, if not, use `pd.to_datetime` to convert them)

You can then use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group your data by creation date. This will internally slice your dataframe into several pieces, one for each distinct value of `Created`, grouping all values with the same creation date together. This way, you can then use aggregation on a creation date level to get the average issue age like so

```py
# [['Created', 'age']] selects only the columns you are interested in
df[['Created', 'age']].groupby('Created').mean()
```

With an additional fourth data point `[a4, 2021/4/20, 2021/4/30]` (to enable some proper aggregation), this would end up giving you the following Series with the average issue age by creation date:

```
                        age
Created                    
2021-04-20 17 days 12:00:00
2021-04-21 55 days 00:00:00
2021-04-23 83 days 00:00:00
```

---

A more condensed way of doing this is by defining a custom function and [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) it to each creation date grouping

```py
def issue_age(s: pd.Series):
    return (s['resolved'] - s['Created']).mean()

df.groupby('Created').apply(issue_age)
```

This call will give you the same `Series` as before.

Comment: Thank you for the response and clear explanation - would this allow me to calc the average age "as at" a range of historical dates?  My end-point is to be able to say: as at 1/6/2021 the avg age of open issues was 22.1 days,  at 3/6/2021 avg age was 24.2 days and so on - for every day in 2021.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your goal can be achieved by filtering your data frame for entries where the `Created` column is older than and the `resolved` column is after your specified date, and then calculate the overall average age on that subset. I don't see an immediate way to vectorize that query, however

Comment: Thanks - yeah you summarised it better than me: calculate average age on subset (and there would be 365 subsets to calc for each year.  At a minimum using apply seems more readable than my looping version. I will have a play with that - thanks again.